# RAML how to define several examples of x-www-form-urlencoded body (post request)

Tags: raml

I'm trying to describe post request to the endpoint. But the problem is that there is only one endpoint, whereas body of a request can contain different parameters. And it's not a problem in JSON format but not in x-www-form-URL encode. Can I define something like this? But not in json format

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
    type: !include schemas/request/accessToken/post.json
    examples:
        passwordGrant: !include ....post.json
        refreshTokenGrant: !include ....post.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this a bug in RAML specification/parser. The RAML parser treats this as a JSON object. The correct is to treat this as a url encoded form.

I create a Issue in RAML specification for this problem:

https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/issues/613